# CSS3 или Javascript как средство для анимации

Tags: css3, javascript

На чем лучше делать анимацию: на css3 или на javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А это уже Вам решать. Все зависит от того, какая у Вас цель.

Если хотите(???????производительности??????) и новых знаний, то **CSS3**, но стоит учитывать **слабую поддержку браузерами**, а если **хотите кроссбраузерного решения**, то однозначно - **javascript/jQuery**.

P.s: Считаю, что CSS3, нужно усиленно изучать, тестировать его возможности. Web-технологии развиваются семимильными шагами, отставать нельзя, но в реальных проектах лучше использовать JS. ИМХО

Comment: проблемы с правописанием вырывают глаза :(

Comment: я также пишу...
а что браузер нагружает сильнее ?
анимация на css3 или на javascript?

Comment: Вот, почитайте - http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/

Comment: Можете почитать статью на хабре - http://habrahabr.ru/company/odnoklassniki/blog/158917/ В комментариях обсуждают производительность...

Думаю, будет интересно.

Удачи.